# Java reflection for generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am using Java Reflection to expose methods in custom eclipse tool.

I am writing method `getReturnType` which accepts `java.lang.reflect.Method` as input and returns object of `Class<?>`

```
private static Class<?> getReturnType(Method method) {
    Type type = ((ParameterizedType)method.getGenericReturnType()).getRawType();
    return getClass(type);
}
```

This code compiles well but at runtime I get the below exception while casting `Type` to `ParameterizedType`.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention that the getClass(type) returns Class<?> for input Type object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't work because you can't assume the result of `getGenericReturnType` will always be a `ParameterizedType`. Sometimes it will just be a `Class` if the return type isn't generic. See this example for how to achieve what you need using `instanceof`:

```
Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();

if (returnType instanceof Class<?>) {
    return (Class<?>)returnType;
} else if(returnType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    return getClass(((ParameterizedType)returnType).getRawType());
}
```

Note that `getGenericReturnType` may return more possible subinterfaces of [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) which you will need to account for somehow, either by handling them also or throwing a runtime exception.

See [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html) for more information/examples.